# Given time off then it was taken back although the company voluntarily give us the time off

Tags: management, rights, time

I work at an international medical facility in VA for a sub contractor business.

During Christmas, the facility shuts down from about the 21st of December until about the 3rd of January. When the facility shut down, our boss told all of us that they were giving us 3 days off as well.

Before the 3 days off date by one and half business days, they took those 3 days back and said we had to work.

Some people have already made arrangements and plans.

Are they allowed to do that since it was just unpaid leave? All of us were notified via mass text message.

Answer (score 3):

I will assume "VA" means "United States, Virginia", not the Swedish City of the name, or the Vatican.

Since Virginia is an "at will" state, the phrase "can my employer do this" becomes pretty meaningless. Outside of a few protected  cases/classes, they could fire you for not coming in as requested... or any other reason... or no reason at all.

"But you promised, and I made plans" is not a protected class.

So can they do this? Yes, they can.

They have the freedom to treat you badly under the threat of firing you and you have the freedom to go look for an employer that treats you better.